# In Oracle Apex How To Fetch Data From One Table To Another Table For Multiple Data Entry Form Using Interactive Grids Or Cursor Query To Fetch Data?

Tags: oracle-apex

my query is how to fetch a record from table A into Table B, i have created a interactive grid which is connected with Table b. I want to fetch record from Table A when i execute the page which is connected with Table B Grids at page load or via button press. Table A holds two column student_id primary, student_name and Table B holds rowid, studentid, studentname, presentdate.

Comment: What have you tried ? Did it fail ? What errors did you get ?

Comment: You mention "Interactive Grid" in the title and "Interactive Reports" in the text. Which one is it - both are very different components.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I Tried Process Using PL/SQL Code, I Didn't Get Any Error But The Record Which I Want To Show In Interactive Reports Columns Is Still Not Showing

Comment: Dear my query is how to fetch a record from table A into Table B, i have created a interactive grid which is connected with Table b. I want to fetch record from Table A when i execute the page which is connected with Table B Grids at page load or via button press.  Table A holds  two column   student_id primary, student_name and Table B holds rowid, studentid, studentname,  presentdate, .

Comment: It's Interactive Grids, By Mistake I Typed Interactive Reports Instead Of Interactive Grids.

Answer (score 0):

Is table B is temporary table or child table..?, you need to execute one more DML action or Plsql action to update or transfer the data from table A to Table B.